# Formula for the average of the lowest remaining value in a sequence of multisets

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, multisets

$B_1=(b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_n)$ is a finite multiset of positive real numbers $b_i$.

To obtain $B_{i+1}$ we let
$$m_i=\min\{B_i\}\quad\quad\quad\quad k_i=\min\{j\in\mathbb{N}:(B_i)_j=m_i\}\\
B_{i+1}=\left(\underbrace{(B_{i})_1-m_i,\ \ldots\ ,(B_{i})_{{k_i}-1}-m_i}\ ,\ b_{k_i}\ ,\ \underbrace{(B_{i})_{{k_i}+1}-m_i,\ \ldots\ ,(B_{i})_n-m_i}\right)$$

In words you take the minimum of the current $B_i$, subtract it from all entries of $B_i$, and replace the leftmost zero by the value at that entry in $B_1$. I'm interested in the average of the values getting subtracted:

$$\underset{n\to\infty}{\lim}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n m_i$$

If all $b_i$ are integers then all $B_i$ are in a finite space, so the sequence of $B_i$s is periodic. By iterating through one period I found some averages and noticed that all of them were:

$$\frac{b_1b_2\ldots b_n}{b_1b_2\ldots b_{n-1}+b_1b_2\ldots b_{n-2}b_n+\ldots+b_2\ldots b_n}$$

Does anyone know where I can find a proof for this?

Comment: Won't such a sequence of integer multisets eventually come to having one or more zeros and stop changing from that moment on?

Comment: @IvanNeretin If there are $n$ zeros in $B_i$, then $n$ of the events occur at the same time. After $n$ iterations the zeros have been replaced by their original initial values all of which are positive.

For each iteration the minimal entry in the multiset (the rightmost if there are multiple minimal) will be replaced by the value of that entry in the initial multiset $B_1$

Comment: Got it. I misread at first and thought that $B_{i+1}$ depends solely on $B_i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $a_N = \sum_{i=1}^N m_i$, this sequence is just $\bigcup_i b_i \mathbb{Z}_+$ (after ordering from small to large and count multiplicity).

For a positive real number $x$, there are $\sum_i \lfloor \frac{x}{b_i} \rfloor =f(x)$ terms of $a_N$ that is $\le x$, hence $a_{f(x)} \le x < a_{f(x)+1}$.

The average waiting time is
\begin{equation}
\text{lim}_N \frac{a_N}{N} = \text{lim}_x \frac{x}{f(x)} = \frac{1}{\sum_i\frac{1}{b_i}}. 
\end{equation}